# Unlock android mobile with PIN code programmatically Selenium mobile automation

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

I have a task that I need to write Android mobile test automation using Appium and selenium in Java.I have to do scenario that phone has to be unlock using PINCODE pro-grammatical way.

Is there anyway to unlock android mobile in automation tests using pincode? Can anyone give me any suggestions to do this task.

Comment: I have gone through some references.But I could not find anything related to unlock using PIN Code.FYI https://discuss.appium.io/t/is-it-possible-to-open-the-lock-by-using-appium-in-android/2612

Comment: Related question: [how to unlock an android phone with password programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66131586/1455694)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no capability in Appium to unlock the pattern/pin lock though appium can wake our device up. To lock/Unlock the screen we need to use ADB commands, below are few examples you can give a try to:

To wake the device from sleep mode

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER
```

To swipe up for obtainging the PIN screen

```
adb shell input swipe 800 400 400 400
```

Enter PIN

```
adb shell input text 0000
```

Tap on Enter to unlock

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER
```